# SSRS Parameter select All with SSAS connection

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dimension in my SSAS model called Customer, I added the parameter to the report for "CustomerNumber", however, I don't want to have a drop down list of customer numbers (Over 5000 customers), So i set the available values to none and default values to none. and set the following into the Parameter Expression of the Dataset:

```
     =IIF(Parameters!CustomerCustomerNumber.Value = "%", 
"[Customer].[CustomerNumber].[All]", 
    "[Customer].[CustomerNumber].&[" & 
Parameters!CustomerCustomerNumber.Value & "]")
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is either enter a single customer number into the parameter text box and receive all records for that customer from the dataset or if you want all customers data just enter %.

My expression above works when entering a customer number but it doesn't when I select all. I suspect the [All] doesn't work how I think. It shouldn't be too hard to do what I have mentioned. Will browse around for answers and post them up.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead .All

```
[Customer].[CustomerNumber].ALLMEMBERS
```

If I understand correctly, .Allmembers gets the invidiviual members within the hierarchy whereas .All points to the collection.